# Material-ui nested grids margins

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to nest a grid using the `material-ui` `<Grid>`. I read the documentation and the examples, but can't accomplish what I want.

I implemented my code this way:

```
                                    <Grid container spacing={4}>
                                        <Grid
                                            item
                                            container
                                            xs={12}
                                            sm={6}
                                            spacing={4}
                                        >
                                            <Field
                                                name="documentNumber"
                                                label="Document Number"
                                                as={TextInput}
                                                error={
                                                    !!(
                                                        touched.documentNumber &&
                                                        errors.documentNumber
                                                    )
                                                }
                                                helperText={
                                                    touched.documentNumber &&
                                                    errors.documentNumber
                                                }
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                fullWidth
                                            />
                                            <Field
                                                name="expirationDate"
                                                label="Expiration date"
                                                component={DatePickerField}
                                                error={
                                                    !!(
                                                        touched.expirationDate &&
                                                        errors.expirationDate
                                                    )
                                                }
                                                helperText={
                                                    touched.expirationDate &&
                                                    errors.expirationDate
                                                }
                                                inputVariant="outlined"
                                                fullWidth
                                                InputProps={{
                                                    labelWidth: 110
                                                }}
                                                InputLabelProps={{
                                                    classes: {
                                                        root: classes.label
                                                    }
                                                }}
                                                openTo="year"
                                                disablePast
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                                            <FileUpload
                                                setDocumentSent={
                                                    setDocumentSent
                                                }
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
```

And the result is this one:

[image: mobile grid]

or this one in desktop:

[image: desktop grid]

Why `material-ui` doesn't add a margin between the nested `<Grid>` like it does for the two outter `<Grid>`?

The expected result should be equally distributed grids, with same margins.

Thanks in advance

Edit: There was an error on my code, I'm editing it but I'm still not achieving the expected result

Comment: You didn't specify the `spacing` property on the inner container.

Comment: Thanks for replying @RyanCogswell. I edited my code, but still can't reach my goal

Comment: Please create a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Here it is @RyanCogswell: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-dirac-co5ep

Comment: you dont want a Grid tag to have an item AND container property, they should be nested like Grid[container] => Grid[item] => Grid[container]

Comment: Thanks @JoeLissner, got it working!

Comment: @JoeLissner are you sure? One of Material UI's own examples on nested grids has Grid components with both the `container` and `item` prop: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/grid/ComplexGrid.tsx#L44

Comment: @MartinDevillers You are correct, this is no longer the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @JoeLissner, I shouldn't have a `<Grid>` being a `Container` and an `Item`.

So, below is my code to whoever has the same question:

```
                            <Grid container spacing={4}>
                                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                                    <Grid container spacing={4}>
                                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                                            <Field
                                                name="documentNumber"
                                                label="Document Number"
                                                as={TextInput}
                                                error={
                                                    !!(
                                                        touched.documentNumber &&
                                                        errors.documentNumber
                                                    )
                                                }
                                                helperText={
                                                    touched.documentNumber &&
                                                    errors.documentNumber
                                                }
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                fullWidth
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                                            <Field
                                                name="expirationDate"
                                                label="Expiration date"
                                                component={
                                                    DatePickerField
                                                }
                                                error={
                                                    !!(
                                                        touched.expirationDate &&
                                                        errors.expirationDate
                                                    )
                                                }
                                                helperText={
                                                    touched.expirationDate &&
                                                    errors.expirationDate
                                                }
                                                inputVariant="outlined"
                                                fullWidth
                                                InputProps={{
                                                    labelWidth: 110
                                                }}
                                                InputLabelProps={{
                                                    classes: {
                                                        root:
                                                            classes.label
                                                    }
                                                }}
                                                openTo="year"
                                                disablePast
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                                    <FileUpload
                                        setDocumentSent={
                                            setDocumentSent
                                        }
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
```

And here is the working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-dirac-co5ep